# Определить должность, по которой средняя зарплата максимальная

Tags: sql

Есть 3 таблицы: `professions(id,profession_name)`, `salary(id,salary)` 
и `staffs(id,fio,profession_id, gender)`. Нужно написать запрос, который определит должность, по которой средняя зарплата максимальна.

У меня получилось сделать только максимальную:

```
select professions.profession_name,  max(salary.salary), staffs.profession_id from professions, salary, staffs where professions.id = staffs.profession_id and salary.id = staffs.id and salary = (select max (salary) from salary) group by professions.profession_name, staffs.profession_id
```

Comment: а почему salary отдельная таблица?

Comment: van9petruk, такое было дано в задании

Comment: отсортируйте по средней и возьмите первую из списка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимый SQL запрос

```
SELECT profession_name, AVG(salary) FROM professions, salary, staffs 
    WHERE staffs.profession_id = professions.id AND salary.id = staffs.id 
    GROUP BY(profession_name)
    ORDER BY avg DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: ERROR:  ОШИБКА:  подзапрос во FROM должен иметь псевдоним
LINE 1: ..._name, MAX(avg_salary) FROM professions LEFT JOIN (SELECT pr...
                                                                                                          
я новичок в sql и не понимаю куда нужно добавить as, стрелка показывает на скобку перед Select

Comment: @mangyst, Postgres требует псевдонимов для подзапросов внутри FROM. Добавте `AS любое_имя` сразу после последней скобки.

Comment: ОШИБКА:  столбец "professions.profession_name" должен фигурировать в предложении GROUP BY или использоваться в агрегатной функции.
Теперь я не могу понять куда поставить group by я пытался поставить  после from но выдает ошибку

Comment: @mangyst я тестировал на SQLite. В PostgreeSQL функция MAX работает по другому.

Comment: @mangyst https://rextester.com/JGM48376

Comment: @van9petryk спасибо, все работает

Answer (score 0):

Для начала в таблицу `staffs` нужно добавить столбец `salary_id` чтобы человеку присвоить id зарплаты. Далее выполнив этот запрос вы получите среднюю зарплату по каждой профессии.

```
SELECT
    professions.profession_name,
    AVG(s.salary),
    staffs.profession_id
from
    staffs
LEFT JOIN salary as s ON (s.id = staffs.salary_id)
LEFT JOIN professions ON (professions.id = staffs.profession_id)
where
    professions.id = staffs.profession_id
group by
    professions.profession_name
```

Для того чтобы получить максимальную среднюю зарплату добавьте в конец запроса 
`ORDER BY s.salary DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: изменять таблицы нельзя

Comment: @mangyst тогда желаю вам удачи

Comment: `salary.id=staffs.id` в исходном запросе есть, так что очевидно Id совпадают в таблицах

Comment: `ORDER BY s.salary` а куда забыли`avg` ?